# transform a 2 js object 2 1 using reduce

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I want to write a function that transfers this objects

```
const input1 = [
  {
    id: "lkhj68C13h8uWh4RJz7",
    post: "on XSS attacks",
    gender: "Littérature",
    postId: "cxTbP5EZjNCxw7rD60L7",
  },
  {
    id: "Kek4ulyC13h8uWh4RJz7",
    post: "The Maze",
    gender: "Littérature",
    postId: "cxTbP5EZjNCxw7rD60L7",
  },
  {
    id: "arfstlyC13h8uWh4RJz7",
    post: "Runner",
    gender: "Littérature",
    postId: "92poye7CF0aprDKcYh1Q",
  },
];

const input2 = [
  {
    postId: "92poye7CF0aprDKcYh1Q",
    postName: "Attalib",
    postUrl: "attalib",
    ville: "Casablanca",
  },
  {
    postId: "cxTbP5EZjNCxw7rD60L7",
    postName: "Atlas",
    postUrl: "atlas",
    ville: "Casablanca",
  },
];
```

to be like a thing like that

```
const output = [
  {
    postId: "92poye7CF0aprDKcYh1Q",
    postName: "Attalib",
    postUrl: "attalib",
    ville: "Casablanca",
    posts: [
      {
        id: "arfstlyC13h8uWh4RJz7",
        post: "Runner",
        gender: "Littérature",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    postId: "cxTbP5EZjNCxw7rD60L7",
    postName: "Atlas",
    postUrl: "atlas",
    ville: "Casablanca",
    posts: [
      {
        id: "Kek4ulyC13h8uWh4RJz7",
        post: "The Maze",
        gender: "Littérature",
      },
      {
        id: "lkhj68C13h8uWh4RJz7",
        post: "on XSS attacks",
        gender: "Littérature",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I tried with Array.reduce, but I don't know how to render this. If anyone has any hindsight on this I want to merge the two inputs using postid,  so can i use map to loop or reduce,I will be very grateful if someone can help me to do that and also if you have any reduce/map tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const input1 = [
  {
    id: "lkhj68C13h8uWh4RJz7",
    post: "on XSS attacks",
    gender: "Littérature",
    postId: "cxTbP5EZjNCxw7rD60L7",
  },
  {
    id: "Kek4ulyC13h8uWh4RJz7",
    post: "The Maze",
    gender: "Littérature",
    postId: "cxTbP5EZjNCxw7rD60L7",
  },
  {
    id: "arfstlyC13h8uWh4RJz7",
    post: "Runner",
    gender: "Littérature",
    postId: "92poye7CF0aprDKcYh1Q",
  },
];

const input2 = [
  {
    postId: "92poye7CF0aprDKcYh1Q",
    postName: "Attalib",
    postUrl: "attalib",
    ville: "Casablanca",
  },
  {
    postId: "cxTbP5EZjNCxw7rD60L7",
    postName: "Atlas",
    postUrl: "atlas",
    ville: "Casablanca",
  }];
const final = input2.reduce((acc, current) => {
    let filtered = input1.filter(obj => obj.postId === current.postId).map(({id,
    post,
    gender,
    postId}) =>  { return {id,
    post,
    gender}});
    current.posts = filtered; 
    acc.push(current);
    return acc;
}, []);
console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a two loop approach and collect all post grouped by their `postId` and map the other array adn add the posts.

```js
const
    input1 = [{ id: "lkhj68C13h8uWh4RJz7", post: "on XSS attacks", gender: "Littérature", postId: "cxTbP5EZjNCxw7rD60L7" }, { id: "Kek4ulyC13h8uWh4RJz7", post: "The Maze", gender: "Littérature", postId: "cxTbP5EZjNCxw7rD60L7" }, { id: "arfstlyC13h8uWh4RJz7", post: "Runner", gender: "Littérature", postId: "92poye7CF0aprDKcYh1Q" }],
    input2 = [{ postId: "92poye7CF0aprDKcYh1Q", postName: "Attalib", postUrl: "attalib", ville: "Casablanca" }, { postId: "cxTbP5EZjNCxw7rD60L7", postName: "Atlas", postUrl: "atlas", ville: "Casablanca" }],
    posts = input1.reduce((r, o) => ((r[o.postId] ??= []).push(o), r), {}),
    result = input2.map(o => ({ ...o, posts: posts[o.postId] || [] }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather poorly worded, but what I assume you are trying to do is assign the `input1` data to objects inside `input2` using the `postId`. What you're doing is sort of complex and not very straightforward, so it's probably best to just do the operation in a for loop or forEach loop.

Here's a quick and dirty outline of what this would look like:

```js
for x in objects in input1 {

    //get the postId

    for y in objects in input2 {
    
        //if an object contains the postId from x, add a new property to y with that information
    }
}
```

If you're looking for how to use `Array.reduce` or `Array.map` you can either look up the [Mozilla Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) or [W3Schools explanation.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp)

Next time you ask a question, try to simplify it to the most basic issue you have. Remember, Google is your best friend. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add an interface for your target type.

If you want to use unknown properties then use:

```
interface LooseObject {
    [key: string]: any
}
```

**Finally:**

```
const output: LooseObject[] = [];

input2.forEach(f => {
  const post: LooseObject = f;
  post.posts = input1.filter(f => f.postId === post.postId);
  output.push(post);
})
```

Demo at [TypeScriptPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmADgVygRhgXhgbQLABQMMA3occXACYBcMARADYDWAFgFYBsAHAMJoBmVt2QB1VgBYASgCkAXgHZ6AGnIVEIaHXrgYADQDKBmAEMoUE8GYQVa4gHMApmCqOATtoAyccwEu3ZshujrZE6ppQAJK0DMAAHgAqAEYACgCsAKIAWuwAcrxxAO4KbgAinAAMnkqqYQC%20tcRkYZQx9ADSjswSyIwAnvxCIuLS8jV2MBpaDAmsjjAAsiZyIY0UTi7uXj5Q-oHBoRSTEdHa8cnp2XkFxWWV1YcwDWrNR9TaJm4AZtD9g8JiSSyRSPYhTKDaKTIMBgdygmAbVweBjePwBKBBVYTcGnBgATgATBo%20o4FLwAGIVEyIMrtYAATVYaAAio9ngQALoAbkIhFAkFgCBQUAJWFwL2xJzahOJpIpVJppTpjJZ8PBuRMAFtHNoAILmEyMOBJNURACqbkYHwNRpNa2IADc4IxGDqGLwTBATElGCYwMATGy1q9wtBcfRzqlMjl8kUSuUquMWsdoBrtXqoL6bPaU1ALVaGGYs-CnS63fQPV6fX6A0HCNzeQQEFB3F9LPNPCBNI4APJJdiOYCwEPEHDMRx9OjQNwIewcuh%20vqEOqN-nQGAgVDCuid7t9gdDnAcsVHnkEQhC1AEgB0XxAbgyllYAAovlgAHykNRr2DgnddiBe37QdYGwL4zzBCJr3BCAxUvdBb2dFs3FfD8YC%20aCpSwTBsHBTCwyoABKCCNy3VBoOQCAX3BYjl0I1dwAgEBXWvRgQHsZ9NygYViKAA).